# How do manufacturers determine LED characteristics?

Tags: led

I have several hundred clear LED's of mixed colour and would like to sort them and determine their characteristics so I can use them. As far as my research tells me, there is no way to determine the forward current of an LED directly, and in order to determine forward voltage you need to know forward current. My question is, how do LED manufacturers determine these values, and is there any way I can do the same?

Comment: I'm pretty sure LED manufacturers determine these by having a precise knowledge of the materials and manufacturing process that went into making them.  Most of the time they probably start off with some target characteristics (200mcd, 3.3v) and then they design the rest of it based on device physics and back out what the remaining characteristics are.  Since I don't actually know this is true I'll leave it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Kit has it basically right --- I'd only add that how the part is packaged (how its attached to the leadframe, the leadframe wire diameters, etc.) also have a strong effect on how much power the part can dissipate, and so how much current it can handle.

Comment: Found this instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/Determining-Forward-Voltages-of-LEDs/ but I haven't read it yet. It knows the current needed, so I don't know if that is needed for this method. Don't have time to look, but I ran across this if anybody would need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about all LEDs can take at least 20 mA. This is almost certainly true of anything in a discrete leaded case, like T1-3/4 or T1. Some small SMD parts may be rated for less.

I would use a 5V supply with a 330 Ω resistor in series. You are very unlikely to have LEDs that can be damaged by this. This will put at most 10 mA through the LED if you get it in the forwards orientation, or 5 V in reverse accross it for the backwards orientation. Neither should hurt ordinary LEDs. 10 mA will be enough for even inefficient LEDs to light up visibly on the bench (assuming typical indoor conditions).

Rig up a jig to show the voltage across the LED. Since the power voltage and resistor are known, you can calculate the current from this too. This will give you one datapoint for voltage and current, which should be good enough for most purposes.

If you don't see the LED light up in either orientation, then keep in mind it could be IR instead of dead. You can use most digital cameras to determine this because they can see the IR light.

Answer (score 1):

I just happened upon [this tutorial](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/376) which answers the problem of sorting the colors for your clear LEDs. Use a microcontroller to switch back and forth so you don't need to worry about polarity. It won't tell you the forward voltage and current specifications, but those would be difficult to actually tell in any case. All you'll really be able to tell is when it turns on, if you go over current you'll likely only know when it's already too late for that LED. If you had known duplicates, this information would be useful, but if each one is its own sample then it's pointless.

Comment: I'm not worried so much about determining polarity or individual colour (this is a trivial problem) - more important to me is knowing what electrical characteristics each diode possesses.